# For a list containing dictionary objects, how do I filter the list based on the value of a key?

Tags: python, json, list, parsing, dictionary

I am writing `json` objects to a separate logfile and a buffered list. I want to get only the list of values corresponding to the key `z_msg` for a condition on the `y_time` key.

Here are six items from the list. How do you make a filter so that you end with a sublist of the four items where `y_time > 1389088007.123000`?

`[{"prompt": "S75U>", "type": "tracelog", "y_time": 1389088007.122344, "z_msg": "\nS75U>\n"},
 {"prompt": "S45U>", "type": "about", "y_time": 1389088007.122945, "z_msg": "S45U>about -b\n"}, 
 {"prompt": "S75U>", "type": "tracelog", "y_time": 1389088007.123140, "z_msg": "\nS75U>\n"},
 {"prompt": "S45U>", "type": "about", "y_time": 1389088007.123441, "z_msg": "S45U>about -b\n"}, 
 {"prompt": "S75U>", "type": "tracelog", "y_time": 1389088007.123842, "z_msg": "\nS75U>\n"},
 {"prompt": "S45U>", "type": "about", "y_time": 1389088007.124541, "z_msg": "S45U>about -b\n"}]`

Comment: I've reformulated it a bit, hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort as proposed by Daniel, or you can use [`heapq.nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest)

```
from heapq import nlargest
top_30 = nlargest(30, my_list, key=lambda x: x['y_time'])
```

For small lists, sorting is probably faster due to a more optimized implementation.  For large lists, you might pick up a performance benefit from heapq due to a better algorithmic complexity (`O(N)` if `N` is reasonably larger than `M` vs `O(NlogN)`<sup>1</sup>).  Finding the break-even point (if there is one) would be a job for `timeit`.

Of course, in either case, if you just want a list of the `z_msg` elements, you can post-process `top_30` with a simple list-comprehension:

```
z_msg = [item['z_msg'] for item in top_30]
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>`N` is the number of elements in `my_list` and you are looking for the top `M` elements</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This is good to know, but I was asking the wrong question initially. Please check the edited question.

Comment: @PaulH -- You can filter with a simple list comprehension:  `[x for x in my_list if x['y_time'] > 1389088007.123]`

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the list by the `y_time` key and then slice the first 30:

```
top_30 = my_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['y_time'], reverse=True)[:30]
```